# Array to string conversion even with types hinting in Laravel Lighthouse

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Hello

When I perform my mutation to create a product, I get the following error: `Array to string conversion`. Full log stack [here](https://gist.github.com/SirMishaa/410c2c2e6a973f2ccc91d41be1548ddd)

For the context, to create a `product`, it is mandatory to create / associate a `brand` and a `category`. You can also specify a `user` who submitted the product but it is not mandatory.

I have tried to understand the error and find solutions but I really can't find the origin of this problem.

Here's my schema :

```
   type mutation {
      # create_brand ... (crud)
      # create_product_category ... (crud)
      
      create_product(input: CreateProductInput! @spread): Product! @create
      update_product(input: UpdateProductInput! @spread): Product! @update
      remove_product(id: ID!): Product! @delete
    }
    
  input CreateProductCategoryInput {
    name: String!
   }
 
 input CreateBrandInput {
    name: String!
   }
    
  input CreateProductInput {
    name: String!
    # ....

    submitted_by: CreateUserBelongsTo
    brand: CreateBrandBelongsTo!
    product_category: CreateProductCategoryBelongsTo!
  }

 input CreateBrandBelongsTo {
    connect: ID
    create: CreateBrandInput
    update: UpdateBrandInput
    disconnect: Boolean
    delete: Boolean
  }

input CreateProductCategoryBelongsTo {
    connect: ID
    create: CreateProductCategoryInput
    update: UpdateProductCategoryInput
    disconnect: Boolean
    delete: Boolean
  }
```

I tried without specify `submitted_by` which is optional.
My GraphQL request is executed like that :

```
mutation($createProductInput: CreateProductInput!) {
  create_product(input: $createProductInput) {
    name
    description
    brand {
      name
    }
    product_category {
      name
    }
    submitted_by {
      username
    }
  }
}
```

And here's, variables of the graphql request :

```json
{
  "createProductInput": {
    "name": "RTX 3090",
    "release_date": "2022-05-08T15:26:35+01:00",
    "cover_image": "https://s3.rekk.app/media/rtx.png",
    "description": "Description here",
    "brand": {
      "create": {"name": "NVIDIA"}
    },
    "product_category": {
      "create": {"name": "Graphical Card"}
    }
  }
}
```

`Product`, `ProductCategory` and `Brand` models can be found here if needed : https://gist.github.com/SirMishaa/987fd95255dee9fe19d2cba5b1d20e25

**Expected behavior/Solution**

**Output/Logs**

Click to expand

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "debugMessage": "Array to string conversion",
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "internal"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "create_product"
      ],
      "trace": [
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php",
          "line": 524,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions::handleError()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.php",
          "line": 57,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Support\\Str::replaceArray()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.php",
          "line": 40,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException::formatMessage()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
          "line": 679,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException::__construct()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
          "line": 638,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection::runQueryCallback()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
          "line": 472,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection::run()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
          "line": 424,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection::statement()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
          "line": 2838,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection::insert()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
          "line": 1560,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::insert()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
          "line": 1028,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::__call()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
          "line": 858,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::performInsert()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Execution/Arguments/SaveModel.php",
          "line": 76,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::save()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Execution/Arguments/ResolveNested.php",
          "line": 36,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\Arguments\\SaveModel::__invoke()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Directives/MutationExecutorDirective.php",
          "line": 89,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Execution\\Arguments\\ResolveNested::__invoke()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Support/Utils.php",
          "line": 98,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\MutationExecutorDirective::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Directives/MutationExecutorDirective.php",
          "line": 91,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Support\\Utils::applyEach()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Directives/MutationExecutorDirective.php",
          "line": 40,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\MutationExecutorDirective::executeMutation()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php",
          "line": 29,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\MutationExecutorDirective::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Directives/MutationExecutorDirective.php",
          "line": 52,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection::transaction()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Directives/RenameArgsDirective.php",
          "line": 33,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\MutationExecutorDirective::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Directives/SpreadDirective.php",
          "line": 34,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\RenameArgsDirective::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Directives/ArgTraversalDirective.php",
          "line": 29,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\SpreadDirective::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Validation/ValidateDirective.php",
          "line": 60,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\ArgTraversalDirective::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Directives/ArgTraversalDirective.php",
          "line": 29,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Validation\\ValidateDirective::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Validation\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Directives/TrimDirective.php",
          "line": 56,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\ArgTraversalDirective::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Factories/FieldFactory.php",
          "line": 92,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\TrimDirective::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Directives\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
          "line": 624,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Factories\\FieldFactory::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Factories\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
          "line": 550,
          "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::resolveFieldValueOrError()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
          "line": 474,
          "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::resolveField()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
          "line": 858,
          "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::GraphQL\\Executor\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::GraphQL\\Executor\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
          "line": 860,
          "function": "array_reduce()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
          "line": 490,
          "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::promiseReduce()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
          "line": 263,
          "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::executeFieldsSerially()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/ReferenceExecutor.php",
          "line": 215,
          "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::executeOperation()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Executor/Executor.php",
          "line": 156,
          "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\ReferenceExecutor::doExecute()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/GraphQL.php",
          "line": 162,
          "call": "GraphQL\\Executor\\Executor::promiseToExecute()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/GraphQL.php",
          "line": 94,
          "call": "GraphQL\\GraphQL::promiseToExecute()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
          "line": 194,
          "call": "GraphQL\\GraphQL::executeQuery()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
          "line": 145,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL::executeQuery()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
          "line": 112,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL::executeOperation()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Support/Utils.php",
          "line": 98,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL::Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/GraphQL.php",
          "line": 111,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Support\\Utils::applyEach()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Support/Http/Controllers/GraphQLController.php",
          "line": 32,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\GraphQL::executeOperationOrOperations()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
          "line": 48,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Support\\Http\\Controllers\\GraphQLController::__invoke()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
          "line": 254,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher::dispatch()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
          "line": 197,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route::runController()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
          "line": 695,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route::run()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 128,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Support/Http/Middleware/AttemptAuthentication.php",
          "line": 32,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 167,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Support\\Http\\Middleware\\AttemptAuthentication::handle()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Support/Http/Middleware/AcceptJson.php",
          "line": 27,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 167,
          "call": "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Support\\Http\\Middleware\\AcceptJson::handle()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 103,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
          "line": 697,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
          "line": 672,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::runRouteWithinStack()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
          "line": 636,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::runRoute()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
          "line": 625,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::dispatchToRoute()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
          "line": 166,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::dispatch()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 128,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
          "line": 21,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
          "line": 31,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest::handle()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 167,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::handle()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
          "line": 21,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php",
          "line": 40,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest::handle()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 167,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings::handle()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
          "line": 27,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 167,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize::handle()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
          "line": 86,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 167,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::handle()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php",
          "line": 52,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 167,
          "call": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors::handle()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
          "line": 57,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 167,
          "call": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies::handle()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
          "line": 103,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
          "line": 141,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline::then()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
          "line": 110,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::sendRequestThroughRouter()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/public/index.php",
          "line": 52,
          "call": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel::handle()"
        },
        {
          "file": "/var/www/html/server.php",
          "line": 21,
          "function": "require_once('/var/www/html/public/index.php')"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

**Versions**

- Lighthouse  : `^5.3` (I guess, it's using the `5.8.3`)
- Laravel : `^8.12` (8.40)

Comment: Can you show your types definition in graphql schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and it causes from "input" being treated as an attribute, and therefore it looks at the input object as a single attribute.

The way to fix this is with the @spread directive, which I see you have already added.

I would therefore say that something is getting cached somewhere.  The schemaSticher uses a library that wraps around file_gets_contents.  To recache file_get_contents you can change the file name.

I would first put your mutations in the schema.graphql file to make sure they work.